# Show that there is no branch of $z^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for $n \gt 1$ in the domain $B(0,1)-\{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that there is no branch of $z^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for $n \gt 1$ in the domain $B(0,1)-\{0\}$

Suppose there is one. Then Since $z^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\log z}$, it is equivalent to saying that $\log z$ has a branch in the mentioned domain. But since $\log z$ doesn't have a branch in the above domain, we are led to a contradiction.

Is this alright??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Excuseme sir, may I have a word with u. Seeing your profile I think u have cleared iit jam. And being a applicant myself in mathematics may u plz have a some advice in these final days?

Comment: @ketan t.amrutam@gmail.com

Comment: Looks right to me.